# intermittent concurrent failues with gradle and junit

Tags: java, gradle, junit, build, junit5

I created a JUnit test class and ran it with Gradle and life was good.

I created another JUnit test class in a different package, ran the same Gradle command and now life has gotten worse.  Worse still, it is intermittently worse.

Sometimes, things work:

```
$ gradle clean cleanTest test

> Task :product:java:common:test

package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyOverrides() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyDefaults() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyTenant() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test1() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test2() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test3() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test4() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test5() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test6() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test7() PASSED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 3s
21 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 16 up-to-date
```

Even then, notice how the left hand side is always `package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest` even though that is only 1 of the test classes.

Sometimes the tests fail:

```
> Task :product:java:common:test FAILED

package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyOverrides() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyDefaults() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyTenant() PASSED
package2.UUIDServiceTests > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.AssertionError

4 tests completed, 1 failed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Notice how the left hand side correctly goes from `package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest` to `package2.UUIDServiceTests`.  This is what I would expect.  The AssertionError is pasted at the bottom of this post.

Sometimes the tests fail differently:

```
> Task :product:java:common:test FAILED

package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test1() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyTenant() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyOverrides() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > onlyDefaults() PASSED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test2() SKIPPED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test3() SKIPPED
package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest > package2.UUIDServiceTests.test4() SKIPPED                                                                                                                                                                   
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '40.9'. Registered test ids: '[:product:java:common:test, 40.1]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '40.9'. Registered test ids: '[:product:java:common:test, 40.1]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor284.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Received a completed event for test with unknown id '40.7'. Registered test ids: '[:product:java:common:test, 40.1]'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Received a completed event for test with unknown id '40.7'. Registered test ids: '[:product:java:common:test, 40.1]'
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.completed(StateTrackingTestResultProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.completed(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor284.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.FailureHandlingDispatch.dispatch(FailureHandlingDispatch.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.run(CurrentBuildOperationPreservingRunnable.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

package2.UUIDServiceTests > initializationError FAILED

java.lang.AssertionError
    Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError

8 tests completed, 1 failed, 3 skipped
```

Again, notice how the left hand side is `package1.DataSourceDetailsUtilsTest` even though a test from `package2.UUIDServiceTests` is the first to run.

This is not a rare occurrence.  About 40% of the time they pass, about 40% of the time they fail in the first fashion, and about 20% of the time they fail in the second fashion

The test classes are very simple.  Only void methods with `@Test` annotation.  No setup or tear downs.  To make sure it is nothing I am doing, I changed literally every test to sleep for 1 second: `Thread.sleep(1000);` and am still able to reproduce the issue.  It seemingly always works when there is only one test class (i.e., if I comment out one of the classes)

After some more research, I do have `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled=true` and if I change that to `false`, then things work again, so I assume Gradle is doing a crap job at concurrency.

Is this not supported?

The AssertionError for first failure scenario:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.results.AttachParentTestResultProcessor.started(AttachParentTestResultProcessor.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.TestClassExecutionEventGenerator.started(TestClassExecutionEventGenerator.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.actor.internal.DefaultActorFactory$BlockingActor.dispatch(DefaultActorFactory.java:122)
at org.gradle.internal.actor.internal.DefaultActorFactory$BlockingActor.dispatch(DefaultActorFactory.java:97)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.started(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.GenericJUnitTestEventAdapter.testStarted(GenericJUnitTestEventAdapter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestExecutionListener.executionStarted(JUnitPlatformTestExecutionListener.java:78)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.lambda$executionStarted$2(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:72)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.notifyTestExecutionListeners(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry.access$100(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:27)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.TestExecutionListenerRegistry$CompositeTestExecutionListener.executionStarted(TestExecutionListenerRegistry.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.ExecutionListenerAdapter.executionStarted(ExecutionListenerAdapter.java:46)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:92)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:169)
at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:189)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:389)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.joinConcurrentTasksInReverseOrderToEnableWorkStealing(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:146)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:169)
at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:189)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doJoin(ForkJoinTask.java:389)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:719)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.joinConcurrentTasksInReverseOrderToEnableWorkStealing(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:146)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:120)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:110)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:71)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService$ExclusiveTask.compute(ForkJoinPoolHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:169)
at java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:189)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6453 ?

Comment: Looks like that is the ticket.  If you make it an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that junit5 parallel test execution with gradle fails and there's a [ticket](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/6453) fot that.